# Theme(legend.position ="top") is not working in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, themes

I'm using this code

```
#GENERAL
ggplot(data_meta_general, aes(x = reorder(Nombre.del.anuncio, +Alcance), y = Alcance, fill = Entrega.del.anuncio)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(legend.position ="bottom") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "Contenidos", y = "Alcance", title = "Top contenidos General") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = Nombre.del.anuncio, y = Alcance , label = scales::comma(Alcance)), 
    hjust = 0.75, size = 3,
    inherit.aes = TRUE)
```

It worked pretty well until I added the theme_classic() line. I want the legend bar to be at the bottom, but theme_classic() moves it to the right. How to fix it?

I tried deleting the theme_classic() line but I really need the graphic to have that theme.

Comment: Put `theme(legend.position ="bottom")` *after* your `theme_classic()` line. The order in which you change the theme matters.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself! I just had to move the theme() code under de theme_classic() line. Now my code looks like this

```
#GENERAL
ggplot(data_meta_general, aes(x = reorder(Nombre.del.anuncio, +Alcance), y = Alcance, fill = Entrega.del.anuncio)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom', plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(x = "Contenidos", y = "Alcance", title = "Top Contenidos General") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = Nombre.del.anuncio, y = Alcance , label = scales::comma(Alcance)), 
    hjust = 0.75, size = 3,
    inherit.aes = TRUE)
```

And works perfectly!